# Arduino Sends Junk value to Android App (App Inventor 2) via Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I just used an arduino code to send text data to an android application which I made in app inventor. I used Bluetooth module HC-05 for connectivity.It almost works but instead of sending few characters, it sends junk data. Here's the arduino code:

```
   void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

}
void loop()
{
  Serial.println("h");
  delay(500);
  Serial.println("s");
  delay(500);
  Serial.println("o");
  delay(500);
}
```

And here's the App blocks and Design:
[image: Blocks]
[image: Design]

And here's the screenshot when I ran the app:
[image: Screenshot]

I click "Show" and I get these random junk data. And the next time I click show, I don't get any data at all. Can anybody explain how to solve this ?

Comment: Try new String (yourbtyes,"utf-8").

Comment: What exactly is the syntax for that?

Comment: I misunderstood your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For Junk values, Try to change the baud rate!
I think you are sending a data from BT device to android device only one time. try running the code continuously in arduino device.

`while(1){
loop();
}`

Answer (score 0):

- Check if you connected BT module to USART0 (RX0, TX0) port
- try change baud rate, usually HC05 has 9600, but it may have also 19200 and sometimes 115200.
- note, that HC05 has 3.3V, and almost all Arduino boards are 5V. So you need to use level shifters. Else specify what board and module you use

Comment: I'm using Arduino Uno

Comment: Your module is a shield with headers?